ANR: com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.ActiveResources.cleanReferenceQueue - Input dispatching timed out
I’m seeing an ANR (Application Not Responding) in my Android app with the following stack trace:
Input dispatching timed out (com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.ActiveResources.cleanReferenceQueue) 
"glide-active-resources" tid=27 Waiting
  at java.lang.Object.wait (Native method)
  at java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java:405)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove (ReferenceQueue.java:207)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove (ReferenceQueue.java:228)
  at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.ActiveResources.cleanReferenceQueue (ActiveResources.java:132)
  at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.ActiveResources$2.run (ActiveResources.java:61)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
  at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.ActiveResources$1$1.run (ActiveResources.java:43)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:1012)

Glide version: 4.16.0
Has anyone else encountered this issue? If so, what did you do to resolve it or mitigate it?
